# Move First Prefab Index of specific Panel, to Last index of another Specific panel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

10 Panels, each with 4 index(1 column), 8 are filled panels and two are empty , I wrote one script to access each index for each panel, Question how can I move first index prefab of a specific panel, to the last empty index of another specific panel ?

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic; 

using UnityEngine;

public class FindingReferenceofAnObject : 
MonoBehaviour { 

// Start is called before the first frame update 

public GameObject ObjectToFind1; 

public GameObject ObjectToFind2; 

public GameObject ObjectToFind3; 

public GameObject ObjectToFind4; 

void Start() {

     ObjectToFind1 = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

     ObjectToFind2= transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;

     ObjectToFind3 = transform.GetChild(2).gameObject;

     ObjectToFind4 = transform.GetChild(3).gameObject;

 
     // how do I transform ?
 }

 // Update is called once per frame

 void Update()

 {
     
 }
```

[image: Image in Game Scene]

Comment: You mean you want to make the first child of this object the last child of another one? Like `var child = transform.GetChild(0); child.SetParent(otherTransform); child.SetAsLastSibling();` ?

Comment: yes please, the first index child of first panel(which is full), move to the last index child for the second panel(which is empty), I have a problem in accessing the panels and moving the children from this point to that point. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please consider that we know nothing about your specific project and use case ... in your context what is a "panel"? what does "empty" mean? What exactly does "move" mean? Like actually change parents or only the positions? And exactly what is your blocker/question?

Comment: as it is shown in the image, each column is a panel itself, so they are 10 panels as I said in the details description, I just want to move the  first child (prefab) from first panel to the last child of the 9th panel which is empty children panel with no prefab. Just want to move the color prefab from this panel to another panel which is 9th the empty one but at the last index.

Comment: So what is the issue? I think I already showed some code that would do that ...

Comment: Okay thank you I know how to get an access, thank you very much ☺️